# Sending email only if two counts don't match and execute a separate script in Perl

Tags: perl, mailx

I am working on a script written in perl that compairs a current_count of IP address and compares it with an expected count.

Currently if current count == normal count then print the word good... if current count does not equal normal count then print the word bad and shows the IP address and current count.

What I'm trying to accomplish is if current count does not equal normal count then print the word bad on screen as it does now but also do two additional things.

1. Send a mailx alert
2. run another script called /home/robertson/stats.sh

Currently it works when i print only on screen:

```
while ..............{
     next if $current_count{$ip_port} == $normal_count && print "ip_port is good";      
     print "$ip_port is bad- Need $normal_count, found only $current_count{$ip_port}\n";
```

My attempt trying to send an email alert and execute stats.sh script if count is bad:

```
while ..............{
     next if $current_count{$ip_port} == $normal_count && print "ip_port is good \n";      
     print "$ip_port is bad- Need $normal_count, found only $current_count{$ip_port} 
&&
 my $body = "$ip_port is bad- Need $normal_count, found only $current_count{$ip_port}";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        "mailx -s \"Missing Counts" Frank.Robertson\@Yahoo.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
&&
/home/roberston/stats.sh;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Remove those stray `&&`.

Comment: Pay attention to the syntax highlighting. Your quotes are a mess.

Comment: Do you know any Perl? Or any programming language in general?

Comment: I recommend to get rid of the more fancy conditionals provided by perl (e.g. `statement if ...` and the use of `&&`). Clean up to use conditionals the boring way (boring is sometimes good). `if (condition){...} else {...}`. Do that and you will either be able yourself to straighten the logic or find more ready help here.

Answer (score -1):

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

while (condition) {
    if ($current_count{$ip_port} == $normal_count) {
        print "$ip_port is good";
        next;
    }

    my $body = "$ip_port is bad- Need $normal_count, found only $current_count{$ip_port}\n";
    print($body);

    my $cmd =
       shell_quote('printf', '%s', $body) .
       ' | ' .
       shell_quote('mailx', '-s', 'Missing Counts', 'Frank.Robertson@Yahoo.com');

    system($cmd);
    die "Can't spawn child: $!\n"                    if $? == -1;
    die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
    die "Child returned error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"     if $? >> 8;

    system('/home/roberston/stats.sh');
    die "Can't spawn child: $!\n"                    if $? == -1;
    die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
    die "Child returned error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"     if $? >> 8;
}
```